# How to remove padding on higher order element from lower order element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is very hacky, but I am stumped. I am using an internal tool to create a webpage. As such, I only have access to some of the generated HTML and CSS due to the nature of these tools.

So, forced upon me is the HTML

```
<div class="example">
    <div class="whatICanAccess">
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS :

```
.example {
padding : 1.6em;
}
```

The only place I can edit my CSS is within the "WhatICanAccess" HTML tag, using style="foo".

Is it possible for me to remove the padding from the outer element ("example") here in any way?

Is it possible for me to remove the padding from the outer element and ONLY have it effect the direct parent of "WhatICanAccess"?

Example is a class that is used throughout the code, and I would only like to remove it in one particular place - but as I say, I cannot add more specific identifiers/tags - I can only edit in this one place.

### Update

I now have this HTML :

```
<div class="example">
   <div class="moreSpecific" style=" padding: -1.8em;>
</div>
</div>
```

but the 1.6em of `.example` is still overriding. What have I done wrong here ?

Comment: So you can only add inline CSS? You don't have access to a separate stylesheet where you can add some overrides? Have you tried something like ... .example:not(:empty) { padding: 0; }

Comment: @Evan No access to separate stylesheets unfortunately, it is very restrictive. No luck with the snippet you posted either. If I target the .example element using Web Developers toolbar and introduce padding:0em; it works but I can't figure out anyway to do this from it's child element in HTML :)

Comment: One way you could go about it is adding position: relative to .example and add position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; to .moreSpecific ( it would also need a set width / height, probably 100% ) this way you can ignore having to work with negative margins

Comment: Here's an example with the :empty http://codepen.io/evanrbriggs/pen/ojzKv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the 1 place a separate class and give it negative margins to balance the padding.

Alternatively, use `position: absolute` & use width and height values. 
With either you don't have to worry about not having access to the parent element.

Tried to make a JSFiddle, but apparently they've removed the "save" option for the time being ...

```
<div class="example">
    <div class="whatICanAccess">
        <div class="noPadding">This div has negative margins and absolute positioning</div>
        <div>This div inherits its padding from 'example'</div>
    </div>
</div>

.example {
    padding : 1.6em;
    height: 400px;
    width 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.whatICanAccess {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.noPadding {
    position: absolute;
    margin: -1.6em 0 0 0;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

If you must use inline CSS...

```
<div style="margin: -1.6em 0 0 0; position: absolute;">This div has negative margins and absolute positioning</div>
```

Comment: I have tried this and had no luck, have I done something incorrectly? Please check out my update. Thanks :)

Comment: You are the man! Negative margin worked a treat :). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `id` of example, you could just use `document.getElementById('example').style.padding='0px';`

Giving your html a negative margin or padding might work too.